# how to loop and group value by checking whether key present or not in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data like below

```
[
    {
        "time": 0,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 4.5,
        "time": 4,
    },
    {
        "time": 5,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 7,
        "time": 6,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 10,
        "time": 8,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 15,
        "time": 11,
    },
]
```

some have `time` only and some have `time and endTime` both

```
the output expecting was:
result : [0, 4.5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15]
```

i.e

- if only `time` there it should be pushed to odd index in array i.e 0 and 5
- if it has `time and endTime` and last result array length is odd, endTime should be pushed i.e 4.5 and 7
- if last result length is even and object have both time and endTime then both values should be added in order i.e time=8 and then endTime=10, 11 and then 15 must be pushed to array.

I tried something like below not working

```
let arrayOfSliderStartEndTime = arr.reduce((pv, cv, i) => {
        if(!("endTime" in cv)) pv.res.push(cv.time)
        else if("endTime" in cv) {
            if(pv.res.length%2 != 0) pv.res.push(cv.time)
            pv.res.push(cv.endTime)
        }
```

Comment: The posted code isn't valid. It looks incomplete.

Comment: what if the current last index is already odd and you want to push time to an odd index?

Comment: That case won't exist, always it's start and end duo.

Comment: I've added the missing parts and it seems to work. What does _"not working"_ mean? Can you post a [mcve]? `pv.res.length%2 != 0` should be `pv.res.length%2 == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code.

```js
let arr = [
    { "time": 0 },
    { "endTime": 4.5, "time": 4 },
    { "time": 5 },
    { "endTime": 7, "time": 6 },
    { "endTime": 10, "time": 8 },
    { "endTime": 15, "time": 11 },
];

let arrayOfSliderStartEndTime = arr.reduce((pv, cv, i) => {
    if (!("endTime" in cv)) {
        pv.res.push(cv.time);
    } else {
        if (pv.res.length % 2 !== 0) {
            pv.res.push(cv.endTime);
        } else {
            pv.res.push(cv.time, cv.endTime);
        }
    }
    return pv;
}, { res: [] }).res;

console.log(arrayOfSliderStartEndTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

An one-liner version:

```js
const result = arr.reduce((r, {time, endTime}) => (r.push(... endTime !== undefined ? r.length % 2 ? [endTime] : [time, endTime] : [time]), r), []);

console.log(...result);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
    {
        "time": 0,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 4.5,
        "time": 4,
    },
    {
        "time": 5,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 7,
        "time": 6,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 10,
        "time": 8,
    },
    {
        "endTime": 15,
        "time": 11,
    },
]
</script>
```